# sweet alert not working on click button that warning not shown while click on button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

code does not give any response on click the delete button while checking also they does not show any
   error while debugging the code also that not showing any error in the debugging mode

```
        $("#delete").click(function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name='clvl']:checked").val();//radio button value
            function delcal(){  
            swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Your Data Deleted permennatly Deleted!",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
                    closeOnConfirm: false,
                    closeOnCancel: false },
                function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "deleteclient.php", //call to file
                                data: {
                                    action: 'editClient', 
                                    clientId:radioValue
                                    },
                                success: function(response) {
                                    //alert(response);

                                },
                                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) { //error callback  

                                    alert('Error: ' + errorMessage );
                                } 
                        }); 
                        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
                    } else {
                        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
                    }
                });
            }


        });
```

Comment: swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success"); shoud be inside success in ajax.

Comment: ok i will check it

Comment: And have in mind when you are using ajax, always validate ajax response in callback(in success).

Comment: No the same error will be occurred while response checking

Comment: Do you call/trigger your function `delcal()` somewhere?

Comment: No i did not delcal() anywhere